# Are POST variables from an HTTPS POST logged by IIS?

Tags: security, iis, post, https

I am investigating the best way to go about securing a webservice call for authenticating users. I have found several usefull posts already on stackoverflow which send me into the right direction. But as I am working for a client with limited resources, the solution should not become a two-month project.

The plan is to use a webservice method that only accepts POST requests using HTTPS. The variables (username and password) will be passed with the formcollection. 
How secure would this be? I don't want these variables to appear in any logfiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, POST variables will not be logged in IIS logs. You could always add server-side code to access the variables and log them in such a manner, but the webserver will not log them by default.